# How to catch this low level MySQL (?) error in PHP/Magento

Tags: php, magento, error-handling

When I'm executing the following statement in Magento with a really large `$sku`, the execution terminates without any errors thrown what so ever. There are no errors in either Magento's, Apache's or PHP's error logs.

> Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

**Question: How do I catch the error?**

I've tried to set custom error handlers, and for testing purposes I've also managed to trigger error situations where each of the error handler functions are invoked. But when running the previously mentioned Magento code with a large `$sku`, none of the error handling functions are executed.

```
error_reporting( -1 );
set_error_handler( array( 'Error', 'captureNormal' ) );
set_exception_handler( array( 'Error', 'captureException' ) );
register_shutdown_function( array( 'Error', 'captureShutdown' ) );
```

For completeness, this is the `$sku` I'm passing to `loadByAttribute()`. (The sku is invalid, but that is not the issue)

> 1- 9685 0102046|1- 9685 1212100|1- 9685 1212092|1- 9685 1212096|1-
>   9685 1102100|1- 9685 1102108|1- 9685 1102112|1- 9685 1102092|1- 9685
>   0102048|1- 9685 0102054|1- 9685 0102056|1- 9685 0102058|1- 9685
>   1212104|1- 9685 1212108|1- 9685 0212058|1- 9685 0104050|1- 9685
>   0212050|1- 9685 0212056|1- 9685 0212044|1- 9685 0212048|1- 9685
>   0212052|1- 9685 0212054|1- 9685 1102104|1- 9685 1102124

Any insight into this matter is much appreciated!

Update:
Upon further investigation, this is the exact point in the code where execution terminates. when the foreach is executed I guess Magento goes into MySQL world and starts loading up data from the database.

\Mage\Catalog\Model\Abstract.php

```
 public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
    {
        $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
            ->setPage(1,1);

        foreach ($collection as $object) { // <--------------- HERE
            return $object;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Note, I'm ONLY interested in finding out how to properly CATCH these kinds of errors, not "fix" the logic**. This is so that I can present a proper error message to the user. The example above with the malformed sku is contrived and I have no desire to make my Magento app work with those erroneous skus.

**UPDATE: CAUSE OF ERROR**

I traced the `load()` call  that is triggered by the `foreach`, and it boils down to a bug Zend / PHP.

I traced the call to \www\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php `_stripQuoted($sql)`, and the following statement:
`$sql = preg_replace("/$q($qe|\\\\{2}|[^$q])*$q/", '', $sql);` (on line 204 in Magento 1.7.0.2).

When `preg_replace` is run with the SQL generated by the `load()` statement, the program just terminates. There is no trace in either apache's or php's log. The log works, because they get filled with other stuff.

[I found this bug report on the issue](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5063). There they indicate it is a segmentation fault. I guess there is 
no way to recover from that (?).

Since the question was explicitly about how to catch the error condition and a lot of the advice here was more about sanitizing the data I don't feel there is a clear cut "winner" for the bounty. But Franklin P Strube at least hinted at doing check deeper down the stack, so he gets it.

Thank you for all you help guys. If you have any advice on how to handle segfaults please do share =).

Comment: terminates , means blank page, browser timeout or what?

Comment: We can say it means a blank page. I'm executing Magento via a script from the terminal and not via a browser. Execution just stops when Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku) is run.

Comment: then it just timeouts or runs out of memory for you, try to load by product id directly see if your SKU fu* this up

Comment: It doesn't timeout. I know it IS the sku that triggers the error. The whole point of the question though is _why_ execution just terminates and why there is no way of catching it.

Comment: and tried try {} catch ?

Comment: Yep =). Forgot to mention the most obvious solution. Yep, I have a try/catch around the function call. No dice, execution terminatates and the catch block isn't catching anything.

Comment: Stupid question, but I assume you have error_reporting set to something like E_ALL | E_STRICT ?

Comment: Hi. Yes that is what error_reporting(-1) does, it means E_ALL | E_STRICT and any other new arbitrary error code that might appear in the future.

Comment: have you tried var_dump'ing the $collection before the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the script may be terminating deeper in the stack than you indicate. When a collection begins the "foreach" loop, it must first call the "load" function, which is specifically where it builds the SQL.

You can try logging `Mage::log((string)$collection->getSelect());` to see if the SQL query has issues.

Or, are you able to sanitize the sku before filtering? Perhaps using an observer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. The issue I'm trying to figure out though is if this error is _catchable_ by user code or not. I haven't been able to catch it. The program just terminates. This makes it very hard to debug  later on. If I were able to catch it I could inform user of my program that something went wrong. Now it just terminates. It is a contrived example and I really don't care what the sku is or if the loadByAttribute call actually works.

Comment: it can't just terminate.. you MUST have an error somewhere logged or displayed on screen (even in console) .. try a bit harder

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register your own error handlers, Magento has already done that for you.
All you need to do is few steps:

1. Turn on error reporting by uncommenting next line in index.php:

   ```
   #ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ```
2. Make sure logging is turned on: go to admin panel
   System->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings, set Enabled to Yes.
   Now you can check the Magento logs in `var/log` from Magento root.

Any php error should fall to php Fatal Error or into the logs.

Comment: I have display_errors on since before, and logging is turned on in Magento. Still no dice. I've also tried with and without my own error handlers. No error is logged in either Magento's, Apache's or PHP's error logs in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the log path in your php.ini, .htaccess or using ini_set.

.htaccess example:

```
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_log /var/www/PHP_errors.log
```

.

If Magento is using PDO, PDO should normally be set into exception mode.

This is what I'm using for PHP 5.2.x:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");

function errhandler($nSeverity, $strMessage, $strFilePath, $nLineNumber){
    error_log(PHP_EOL.date("Y-m-d H:m:s", time())." ".$strFilePath."#".$nLineNumber.": ".$strMessage.PHP_EOL);
    throw new ErrorException($strMessage, /*nExceptionCode*/ 0, $nSeverity, $strFilePath, $nLineNumber);
}
set_error_handler("errhandler", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

this problem occurs when PHP run out of memory,

increase allowed memory size from php.ini
or increase memory limit on fly,

put this `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Answer (score 0):

In index.php, move the following line to the top of the index.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I have a feeling your issue is not flagging this trigger because of a permissions issue. I run these two commands to ensure permissions are set correctly on files/dirs.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

First two questions :

- How do you know there actually is an error ? An `exit` in some part of the php code, for example, will not raise an error and yet the script will be terminated.
- You say `"I guess Magento goes into MySQL world and starts loading up data from the database"`. Have you checked what happens on your MySQL server ? Does the SQL query really get sent ? If it is sent, is it treated, errored, or stalled ?

I would suggest using a debugger to step through the PHP code, starting from the `foreach ( $collection` line. I don't know what editor/IDE you are using, you can setup [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) to allow setting breakpoints and stepping through the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. That debuging is exactly what I have done, and the execution just stops at the statement I pointed out above. It is a foreach statement, so I can't step into that statement. I never get to the inner block of the foreach. It terminates just "before" one would expect the to step into the foreach's block. I'm just guessing, but I think that the collection gets loaded at that point by Magento, and Magento starts building an SQL query and around there it breaks. But anyhow, that is actually irrelevant. How do I catch that in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is the `foreach` that kills the script.

Try disassembling the call immediately before:

```
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $res1 = $this->getResourceCollection();
    $res2 = $res1->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes);
    $res3 = $res2->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value);

    $collection = $res3->setPage(1,1);

    foreach ($collection as $object)
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise, you might want to simply throw an exception if the SKU length is excessive, or if the SKU fails some sanitization check.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error for a customer in Magento 1.7.

I have a sql insert statement wich saves the sidebar cart html in a field, and in that statement I used addslashes for that html.

When there are 1 to 5 products in that html, the save statement executes succesfully.

When there are more than 5 products, so that means the html is longer but the part for each product is the same, I run also in this error.

The program just stops at $sql = preg_replace("/$q($qe|\\{2}|[^$q])*$q/", '', $sql); and no errors are visible.

It seems to be a memory problem, with 6 products I cross a limit in size (now 7000 characters), so the provider has to change php settings I guess ..